# ColdFusion HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7, coldfusion

After installing ColdFusion I got "HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found" with error code:0x80070032, when I open my admin url i.e. `http://127.0.0.1/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm`.

My IIS version is 7, ColdFusion 9 with update 9.01, Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: I would turn on directory browsing in IIS and  I would work my way through each part of the url to see where things are missing.